# CakePHP 3 look at plugin controller first

Tags: cakephp, themes, cakephp-3.0

My website has multiple plugins (themes). For 1 theme I want a special controller. I want that controller located in the plugin/src/controller folder.

What do I have to change to let CakePHP look if there is a controller with that name in the plugins controllers folder before it looks in the normal controllers folder?

Comment: Please remind that plugins and themes are different things in cakePHP! Plugins contain code and are "independet" programms while themes are just different views, e.g. a blue desktop theme, a red mobile theme, and so on!

Comment: That's not really true. The reason they're actually **not**  that much different they've been removed in CakePHP 3.0 and are simply yet another plugin. See http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/themes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a custom route class that you'll use for the route to that controller(s).

See [the routing chapter of the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html) for how to do that.

Inside your route you'll implement the logic that checks if the actual controller file you expect is present or not and define a callback. You can use the route options array to define a call back as well, this would make it more re-useable.